# Clarification of the notions of argument, statement, assertion, premise, proposition, syllogism, predicate, subject, deduction and conclusion

Tags: logic

As in the title can you give a succint explanation that goes beyond definitions?

Edit: Here is what I understand of these so far.

- A [premise](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/premise) is one of two [propositions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proposition).
- I am not yet clear about [how a proposition and statement differ](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10894/what-is-the-difference-between-a-statement-and-a-proposition).
- A proposition is the contents of an [assertion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assertion) which can be true or false.
- One of two propositions contains a term called a [predicate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/predicate) that can be used to support the [conclusion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conclusion) of a [syllogism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/syllogism).
- A [syllogism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/syllogism) is a type of [argument](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/argument) and an argument is a series of [propositions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proposition) with the the final [proposition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proposition) being a [conclusion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conclusion)?

Comment: 1) an argument may have more than ore *premises*.

Comment: 2) [proposition](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositions/) is an "overloaded" philosophical word; usually, it means a non-linguistic object, like the *meaning* of a sentence (the linguistic object).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So a syllogism is a specific argument that has just the two premises?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So a proposition is "language-agnostic" or absolute with statements being linguistic such as  _The snow is white_ and _La neige est blanche_ corresponding with the same proposition?

Comment: Yes; a syll is a three-sentences argument: two premises and one conclusion.

Comment: _Mortality is the predicate and the term Humanity is the subject_ Interesting. I wonder if this has been combined with ontological views.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily treat these as overly technical terms. A premise is a claim that must hold true for an argument to work. Think of it like a foundation. A premise is often defined as an "assumption," and while some premises are assumptions, some are also argued for in their own right. The number of premises isn't necessarily two. A proposition, a statement, and an assertion are the same thing, depending on context. Are you dealing with philosophy of language?

Comment: @Student _Are you dealing with philosophy of language_ Not directly but I do wish to understand how arguments are constructed and be able to analyse them.

Comment: One kind of proposition well-know in logic is the [categorical proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition) that is the core of [Aristotelian logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/) : "Every Human is Mortal", "Some Cats are Black". Their "logical form" is respectively: "Mortality belongs to all Men" where Mortality and Humanity are *terms*.

Comment: For a clear introduction, you can see Ch.1 of Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&pg=PA1) (2003).

Answer (score 1):

A sentence is a *statement* or an *assertion* telling you the facts of the matter; its not asking you to evaluate whether it is true or not.

> Socrates is Greek

A sentence is a *proposition* when it is asking you to evaluate whether it is true or not; in English this is shown by a sentence in the form of a question

> Is Socrates Greek?

In formal logic question marks aren't used; one has to understand this from the context; I could write this out as

> IsGreek(Socrates)

This makes it obvious what the connection is to the above sentence; there are two parts to this sentence and the first part 'IsGreek' is called the predicate, and the second part 'Socrates' is called the subject.

This is a style of refering to propositions that one sees in verbose programming languages; but equally I could write it out more enigmatically as:

> G(Socrates)

which by merely looking at it without any explanation tells you very little...could you guess that G(x) stands for "Is x Greek?"