# Difference between Propositions and Statements

Tags: propositional-logic

I have read the answers to many questions like mine I reached these two definitions of propositions (I don't know which one is correct)

1. A proposition is a statement that can be true or false.
   If this is true then what characteristic should a statement have to have a truth value?
   And can you provide examples of statements that have a truth value and the ones that don't
2. A proposition refers to the language-independent core meaning of sentences. Statements merely express propositions so statements are true in virtue of the propositions.

Which one is correct? I am just so confused :(

Then I tried to figure it out on my own but there were just too many explanations on the internet, I even tried getting help from AI, but it said this which confused me even more: it is possible for a sentence that has a proposition inside to not be a statement. This is because the proposition inside the sentence can be a complicated one

A sentence that contains a proposition is considered a proposition itself only when the sentence is simple and can be evaluated as true or false in the language of formal logic.

Comment: Does this help: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/10896/47749?

Comment: [Both](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proposition) are correct. A lot of words have ambiguous uses, this is one of them. In philosophy, the second use is vaguely closer to what is more common, see [SEP, Propositions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositions/):"The term ‘proposition’ has a broad use in contemporary philosophy. It is used to refer to some or all of the following: the primary bearers of truth-value, the objects of belief and other “propositional attitudes” (i.e., what is believed, doubted, etc.), the referents of that-clauses, and the meanings of sentences."

Comment: I have already read that it has helped me a bit :) J Kusin

Comment: Well-formulated question. You need to, if you *are* confused, work on your logic.